# parse jsonarray array within array within array

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am using the under mentioned json to parse data and its crashing at

```
JSONObject eachData2 = user6.getJSONObject(n);
```

I am trying to retrieve lat/lng from the array .Please let me know where the mistake is and also if I can make the json parsing code shorter than the one below.I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.

```
        String jsonLocation = null;
        try {
            jsonLocation = converJsonToStringFromAssetFolder("datajson", getBaseContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JSONObject mainObject = null;
        try {
            mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonLocation);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONArray new1 = null;
        try {
            new1 = mainObject.getJSONArray("data1");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < new1.length(); i++) { 
            JSONObject c = null;
            try {
                c = (JSONObject) new1.get(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject user = null;
            try {
                user = c.getJSONObject("latlng");
                JSONArray user2 = user.getJSONArray("geoset1");


                for (int j = 0; j < user2.length(); j++) {

                    JSONArray user3 = user2.getJSONArray(j);


                    for (int k = 0; k < user3.length(); k++) { 

                        JSONArray user4 = user3.getJSONArray(k);

                        for (int l = 0; l < user4.length(); l++) { 

                            JSONArray user5 = user4.getJSONArray(l);

                            for (int m = 0; m < user5.length(); m++) { 



                                JSONArray user6 = user5.getJSONArray(m);

                                 for (int n = 0; n < user6.length(); n++) { 




                                JSONObject eachData2 = user6.getJSONObject(n);

                                if (n==0) {
                                    JSONObject eachData = user6.getJSONObject(n);


                                } else {
                                    JSONObject secondData = user6.getJSONObject(n);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }


            } }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }





}

public static String converJsonToStringFromAssetFolder(String fileName,Context context) throws IOException {
    AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream file = manager.open(fileName);

    byte[] data = new byte[file.available()];
    file.read(data);
    file.close();
    return new String(data);
}
```

}

**Json**

```
{
    "dataset": "dataset1",
    "data1": [
        {
            "dataset2": "dataset21",
            "dataset3": {
                "dataset31": 1,
                "LAT": 70.0187,
                "LON": "-141.0205"
            },
            "latlng": {
                "latlng1": "latlngset1",
                "geoset1": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                70.0187,
                                -141.0205
                            ],
                            [
                                70.1292,
                                -141.7291
                            ],
                            [
                                70.4515,
                                -144.8163
                            ],
                            [
                                70.7471,
                                -148.4583
                            ],
                            [
                                70.7923,
                                -151.1609
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                71.147,
                                -152.6221
                            ],
                            [
                                71.4307,
                                -154.8853
                            ],
                            [
                                71.5232,
                                -156.7529
                            ],
                            [
                                71.5232,
                                -156.7529
                            ],
                            [
                                71.5232,
                                -156.7529
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                71.1185,
                                -153.9954
                            ],
                            [
                                64.3922,
                                -167.0142
                            ],
                            [
                                64.0554,
                                -165.7343
                            ],
                            [
                                64.0193,
                                -163.2294
                            ],
                            [
                                63.9615,
                                -162.1143
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: in json file , can not acceptable in reading of file this will generate error  so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote too much `for` loops:

`user6` is `int` type: `int user6 = user5.getInt(m);`

Here is a fix:

```
JSONObject mainObject = null;
    try {
        mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray new1 = null;
    try {
        new1 = mainObject.getJSONArray("data1");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < new1.length(); i++) { 
        JSONObject c = null;
        try {
            c = (JSONObject) new1.get(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject user = null;
        try {
            user = c.getJSONObject("latlng");
            JSONArray user2 = user.getJSONArray("geoset1");


            for (int j = 0; j < user2.length(); j++) {

                JSONArray user3 = user2.getJSONArray(j);


                for (int k = 0; k < user3.length(); k++) { 

                    JSONArray user4 = user3.getJSONArray(k);

                    for (int l = 0; l < user4.length(); l++) { 

                        JSONArray user5 = user4.getJSONArray(l);

                        for (int m = 0; m < user5.length(); m++) { 



                            doubleuser6 = user5.getDouble(m);

                            System.out.println(user6);
                        }

                    }

                }


            } }catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Output:

```
70
-141
70
-141
70
-144
70
-148
70
-151
71
-152
71
-154
71
-156
71
-156
71
-156
71
-153
64
-167
64
-165
64
-163
63
-162
```

Comment: agree with @Maxim , You are trying to convert an int value to a JSONArray.

Comment: Thanks Maxim but how do I get the double ?? in this case lat/lng

Comment: Cool used  double f = user5.getDouble(m); .Thanks Maxim

Comment: Why did I get -2 for asking question ?? can someone remove that .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi there this looks quite komplex but if you are willing to use [GSON](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) this could be converted to a JAVA Object with just a few lines.

Comment: Hello Soma.What is the advantage of using GSON over JSON ? And how do I resolve the above issue ? I appreciate any help .Thanks again.

Comment: The advantage of using gson, is that you get a full Class filled with your JSON Data, without managing the loops and the count of your Objects in JSON

Comment: Thanks for that Soma .How do I implement the above json code to GSON.Where can I start ??

Comment: Just follow the Tutorial, or search for other GSON tutorials, you do not have to change the JSON just generating a DataObject class to fit your needs. Have Fun!